# Botão "continuar" para exibir div para inserir senha no form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo um form de login básico para o usuário inserir o email e logo depois clicar no botão "continuar" e abrir o input para ser colocado a senha, porém no código que fiz o elemento já inicia aparecendo na página e se eu clico no botão ele se esconde, e não o contrário que é o meu objetivo.

Já tentei deixar a propriedade da div no css com `display: block` mas nesse caso o input continua a aparecer normalmente e o botão até para de funcionar

Também tentei alterar as condições do if, mas não consegui alcançar esse resultado

Essa parte do meu formulário está assim:

```
<html>
  <!-- CSS -->
<style>
  input{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  button{
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>

<!-- JS -->

 <script>
    function exibirsenha() {
      var exibir = document.getElementById("password");
      if (exibir.style.display === "none") {
        exibir.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        exibir.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
  <form-group>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </form-group>

  <div id="password">
    <form-group>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
    </form-group>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" onclick="exibirsenha()">Continuar</button>

  </form>
</html>
```

É uma dúvida de inciante, peguei a parte do JavaScript no w3schools mas não consegui chegar no resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta vc já iniciar a `div` com `display:none` no `style`, repare que na `div#password` eu coloquei um `style="display: none"`

```html
<html>
  <!-- CSS -->
<style>
  input{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  button{
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }

</style>

<!-- JS -->

 <script>
    function exibirsenha() {
      var exibir = document.getElementById("password");
      if (exibir.style.display === "none") {
        exibir.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        exibir.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
  <form-group>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </form-group>

  <div id="password" style="display:none">
    <form-group>
      <input  type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
    </form-group>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" onclick="exibirsenha()">Continuar</button>

  </form>
</html>
```